# Rails 3 change div id with dropdown box

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I want to add a setting on my Rails 3 web app to change an image on the users page. The content is `<div id="imac">` and with a dropdown box, I would like to make it change the div id from `imac` to, lets say, `macbook`. How would I go about doing this?

I'm guessing I need to create a migration to `add_divid_to_users`, or similar, and then depending on what div it is selected, it shows it on the userpage.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could do it that way. If you just want to differentiate between images for CSS then you might think about using the id of image as the id of the div instead so you can get away with not adding the extra column to the table.

Something like:

```
<div id="<%= @user.image.id %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with some basic javascript:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my_div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #imac { background: red; }
    #macbook { background: green; }
    #iphone { background: blue; }
</style>
<select id="div_changer" onchange="document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].id=this.value">
    <option value="imac">Imac</option>
    <option value="macbook">Macbook</option>
    <option value="iphone">IPhone</option>
</select>
<div id="imac" class="my_div"></div>
```

Then it's up to you if you want to store the selected value of the dropdown in the database as well.